# How to do the pattern matching in 'if' condition in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_pop1
AS
ROUTERNAME_V varchar2(100);
BEGIN
SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID
INTO ROUTERNAME_V
FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
WHERE rownum < 2;
IF  CHARINDEX('RNS',ROUTERNAME_V) > 0
dbms_output.put_line(routername_v);
ELSE
PRINT 'It doesn''t Contain'
END;
```

/* HERE I AM TRYING TO DISPLAY THE RECORDS ONLY IT STARTS WITH 'RNS' STRING
 I am getting error like :

---

10/3     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_OUTPUT" when expecting
         one of the following:
         * & - + / at mod remainder rem then  and or
         || multiset
         The symbol "*" was substituted for "DBMS_OUTPUT" to continue.

10/37    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . ( * % & - + / at mod remainder rem then 
         and or || */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHARINDEX` and `PRINT` are not Oracle functions. Unless you've defined those yourself as wrappers, you'll need to switch to functions Oracle does recognise. You're also missing `THEN` and `END IF`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_pop1
AS
  ROUTERNAME_V varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID
  INTO ROUTERNAME_V
  FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
  WHERE rownum < 2;

  IF INSTR(ROUTERNAME_V, 'RNS') > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(routername_v);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('It doesn''t Contain');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

You said you wanted the string to start with `RNS`, and `INSTR` will find it anywhere; you'd need to test that it returns exactly 1, not > 0.

You could also do:

```
  IF ROUTERNAME_V LIKE 'RNS%' THEN
```

`DBMS_OUTPUT` puts the text into a buffer that something else can then retrieve, so you'll only see anything if your client is expecting this when it is executed (not just when it is compiled); e.g. with `set serveroutput on` in SQL*Plus, or by opening the DBMS Output panel in SQL Developer. You generally shouldn't rely on that being available.

```
set serveroutput on
exec get_pop1;
```

The `get` in the procedure name suggests that maybe you really want a function that returns the value, or the fixed string if it doesn't match your pattern.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pop2
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  ROUTERNAME_V varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID
  INTO ROUTERNAME_V
  FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
  WHERE rownum < 2;

  IF ROUTERNAME_V LIKE 'RNS%' THEN
    RETURN(routername_v);
  ELSE
    RETURN('It doesn''t Contain');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
select get_pop2 from dual;
```

---

It might be worth noting that you're selecting an arbitrary row from your table. If it has more than one row there is nothing to determine which one you get; the same query against the same data could get a different row back. You need a filter and/or an `order by` to control which you get, e.g. the most recent record if they are time-stamped.

Comment: One more doubt is how to display the data once it is executing in command mode..?

Comment: @user3165241 - I'd already added a note about relying on DBMS_OUTPUT. How you get that to display depends on your client. I've shown how to turn it into a function as well, which might be more useful. Depends what you need to do with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, These information is more usefull to me. I think it may help others who has started as beginer

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_pop1
AS
ROUTERNAME_V varchar2(100);
BEGIN
SELECT TRAFFIC_CUST_ID
INTO ROUTERNAME_V
FROM INTERFACE_ATTLAS
WHERE TRAFFIC_CUST_ID LIKE '%RNS%' and rownum < 2;
IF  CHARINDEX('RNS',ROUTERNAME_V) > 0 THEN
dbms_output.put_line(routername_v);
END;
```

I'm not sure you want the String RNS at the beginning or not, you may want to replace '%RNS%' by 'RNS%'.

Comment: You forgot the 'THEN' at the end of the line beginning with 'IF'

Comment: I have tried for above code I am getting error like :Errors for PROCEDURE GET_POP1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
11/4     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:
         if

Comment: Hi , I have included END IF ,so that error has gone

Comment: This error is appearing : LINE/COL ERROR -------- ------------------------------------------------------ : 9/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored 9/5 PLS-00201: identifier 'CHARINDEX' must be declared

Comment: You don't need this block of code: the select ensures that the returned row contains RNS. Remove the 'IF CHARINDEX('RNS',ROUTERNAME_V) > 0 THEN' and the 'END IF'